# SSSD Configuration to Authenticate a one-way trusted domain user

Tags: authentication, active-directory, sssd

I have a Microsoft "REDFOREST" Active Directory Deployment.  I have my REDFOREST domain with all my user accounts.  I have my "RESOURCE" domains that have a one-way trust of the REDFOREST domain.

I have setup my AD sites and services where each RESOURCE domain as its own SITE/vlan/subnet.  A firewall restricts traffic to only allow domain DC-to-DC replication as needed between the sites/vlans and isolate the RESOURCE domain site/vlan with the RESOURCE hosts.  On the RESOURCE domain/site I have a RODC for my REDFOREST domain and a ServerCore DC for my RESOURCE domain.  Replication all works good.  My windows clients are joined to the RESOURCE domain and I can login as my REDFOREST user as desired.  On my Ubuntu systems, I've configured SSSD and joined the RESOURCE domain.  I can login as my user@resource.domain without issue.

**Problem** : I cannot figure out how to login to the Ubuntu workstations as my redforest user.  I enabled debug logs for SSSD.  I can see SSSD getting the domain trust info and querying the RODC for the user as desired, however has several errors.

- Port status of port 389 for server '' is 'not working'
- No user found with filter
- No entry with upn  found

I see SSSD determine the domain controller to use and "calling ldap_search_ext" with an ldap filter looking for my user account.  I've manually run "ldapserach" using the same filters to retrieve my account info successfully.  It appears that since AD does not allow an anonymous bind and/or since my system doesn't have a kerberos ticket (since it belongs to the RESOURCE domain, not the REDFOREST domain), the host cannot lookup my account in the REDFOREST domain (because REDFOREST does not trust RESOURCE).

I was looking through the SSSD documentation and was wondering there is a good/secure way to specify maybe a service account to bind/use for the REDFOREST domain user lookups.  Or maybe some kerberos configuration, or LDAP, or another idea to allow this domain topology to work for the Ubuntu workstations.

Diagram for Reference.
[REDFOREST-RESOURCE DOMAIN DIAGRAM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFL1Z.png)